# Disassociate EIP before detaching IGW

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

When I modify the subnet of my VPC, a whole new VPC is provisioned. The IGW is moved from the old VPC to the new one. Which would be fine if it wasn't prevented from moving because the Elastic IP is still attached to the instance.

I tried many combinations with `depends_on`.

If I manually disassociate the EIP, terraform IGW modification stops waiting for ever.

```
########################
#      ELASTIC IP      #
########################
resource "aws_eip" "ip" {}

# EIP association isolated for testing "depends on"
resource "aws_eip_association" "eip_assoc" {
  instance_id   = "${aws_instance.vpn_server.id}"
  allocation_id = "${aws_eip.ip.id}"
  depends_on = ["aws_internet_gateway.gw","aws_vpc.vpc"]
}

########################
#    VPC CREATION      #
########################
resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  cidr_block       = "${var.cidr}"
  enable_dns_support = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  assign_generated_ipv6_cidr_block = "${var.ipv6}"
}

########################
#    IGW CREATION      #
########################
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "gw" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
}

########################
#      Instance        #
########################
resource "aws_instance" "vpn_server" {
  ami           = "${data.aws_ami.ami_amzn2.id}"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name = "${aws_key_pair.key.key_name}"
  subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.a.id}"
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  ipv6_address_count = 1
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_default_security_group.sg.id}"]
  lifecycle { create_before_destroy = true }
  depends_on = ["aws_internet_gateway.gw"]
  user_data = "${data.template_file.user_data.rendered}"
}

########################
#   Subnets Creation   #
########################
data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {}

resource "aws_subnet" "a" {
    availability_zone = "${data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[0]}"
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
    cidr_block = "${cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.vpc.cidr_block, 2, 0)}"
    map_public_ip_on_launch = true

    # Bug Issue 688: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/688
    # Soon set even if no IPv6 for VPC
    # https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/pull/2103
    ipv6_cidr_block = "${var.ipv6 ? cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.vpc.ipv6_cidr_block, 8, 10) : ""}"
    assign_ipv6_address_on_creation = true
}
```

Any idea what would be the correct way of disassociating the EIP before the IGW tries to move to the new VPC?

Comment: Internet Gateways don't cost anything, so it's hard to see a reason to move an IGW from one VPC to another.

Comment: @chriscatfr When you modify the subnet are you changing "${aws_subnet.a.id}"?  If so, can you show that code?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, Terraform is the one wanting to move it from the old VPC. I simply wanted to change the VPC ip range and keep the same Elastic IP for my server.

Comment: @kenlukas, I edited the question to add the subnet

Comment: the only thing I change is the vpc cidr_block, which is also used by the subnet. This question is only about what happens when I try to change only this CIDR. Some dependencies are wrong: the IGW cannot be detached from the old VPC until I disassociate the EIP.